# Bash parse output in route command

Tags: linux, bash, networking

I am writing a bash script to register the remote hosts in a wireless network. I am getting the remote IPs, but I need help to parse the output. Here's my output:

```
$ IPS=`route -n | grep -e '10.0.0' | awk '{ print $1 }'`
$ echo $IPS
10.0.0.2
10.0.0.3
```

I need to get these IPs and insert into a command like `... <remote_ip_1> ...`

How can it be done? I couldn't find this case in the answers.

Thank you

Comment: If you need to process things line-by-line consider a `while` loop, but perhaps if you explain your ultimate goal another solution might be an even better fit

Comment: Unquoted `$IPS` would not produce that output.

Comment: Can you show us with an actual example, from an actual IP range you want to filter to an actual command you want to form out of it

Comment: [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) *("How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?")* is rather directly on-point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like

```
route -n | awk '/10.0.0/ { system("command to be executed with "$1) }'
                                                                  ^
                                                             added missing )
```

We are negating the use of grep and using // to search for the text required and then the awk system function to execute a command along with $1

Comment: Using textual substitution to form shell commands lends itself to shell injection attacks. Granted, it might tricky for an attacker to inject content into `route -n` -- but this is still a rather questionable idiom to make a practice of.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
route -n | grep -e '10.0.0' | awk '{ print $1 }' | xargs -L 1 your_command
```

For example, try the following:

```
route -n | grep -e '10.0.0' | awk '{ print $1 }' | xargs -L 1 echo "===>"
```

The argument -L 1 tells xargs to run one command per IP. See man xargs for more details

Comment: `awk /10[.]0[.]0/ { print $1}` avoids the need for a separate `grep` (while fixing a bug in your existing code: In `grep -e '10.0.0'`, as in any other regex context, the `.`s are wildcards; thus, `printf '%s\n' 10a0b0c | grep -e '10.0.0'` matching.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I just suggested the Unix Raman was looking for - it is xargs with -L 1. Sure, we can use just awk for this task...